# sqlite - asc/desc result is inverted

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

Why is the following query working inverse? I'd expect that asc order them in alphabetical order..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply CAPS to the commands and apply 'NOCASE' function like:

```
SELECT * FROM giochi ORDER BY nomegioco NOCASE (ASC)
```